# Change the data type of one element in a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, abstract-data-type, complex-data-types

I'm looking to implement a hardware-efficient multiplication of a list of large matrices (on the order of 200,000 x 200,000). The matrices are very nearly the identity matrix, but with some elements changed to irrational numbers.

In an effort to reduce the memory footprint and make the computation go faster, I want to store the 0s and 1s of the identity as single bytes like so.

```
import numpy as np
size = 200000
large_matrix = np.identity(size, dtype=uint8)
```

and just change a few elements to a different data type.

```
import sympy as sp

# sympy object
irr1 = sp.sqrt(2)    

# float
irr2 = e               

large_matrix[123456, 100456] = irr1
large_matirx[100456, 123456] = irr2
```

Is is possible to hold only these elements of the matrix with a different data type, while all the other elements are still bytes? I don't want to have to change everything to a float just because I need one element to be a float.

-----Edit-----

If it's not possible in numpy, then how can I find a solution without numpy?

Comment: Numpy arrays do not allow mixed types.  This can be done in Pandas (dataframe) and xarray (similar to numpy arrays and similar to pandas dataframe).

Comment: An alternative approach is to apply a scaling factor to your non-integer data (if you can), then convert this value to an integer.  For example, if you only need the first three decimal places of pi, then apply a scaling factor of 1000 and convert to int (inserted value will be 3141)

Comment: Mixing types is not going make the calculation go faster.  `numpy` gains its speed by treating all elements of the array the same way in compiled code.  There are no speed advantages to calculating with `uint8`.  Modern processors are optimized to work whit `float64` and `int64` numbers.  Any attempt to mix dtypes will slow it down.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can have a look at the SciPy's [Coordinate-based sparse matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html). In that case SciPy creates a sparse matrix (optimized for such large empty matrices) and with its coordinate format you can access and modify the data as you intend.

From its documentation:

```py
>>> from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
>>> # Constructing a matrix using ijv format
>>> row  = np.array([0, 3, 1, 0])
>>> col  = np.array([0, 3, 1, 2])
>>> data = np.array([4, 5, 7, 9])
>>> m = coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(4, 4))
>>> m.toarray()
array([[4, 0, 9, 0],
       [0, 7, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 5]])
```

It does not create a matrix but a set of coordinates with values, which takes  much less space than just filling a matrix with zeros.

```py
>>> from sys import getsizeof
>>> getsizeof(m)
56
>>> getsizeof(m.toarray())
176
```

Comment: OP asked specifically about putting mixed types within the array.  How does this allow for mixed types?  I am unfamiliar with coordinate-based sparse matrix, but it does not seem to allow mixed data types.

Comment: For sparse matrices it simply creates a list of coordinates and their corresponding values without actually creating any array at all. This way all non-zeros are ignored. I updated my answer to better illustrate the size expansion when it is transformed into a matrix.

Comment: The nonzero elements still have to have the same `dtype`, and the dtypes that it can use for calculations is even more restricted (compared to dense arrays).  Speed isn't that great, except for matrix multiplication on sufficiently sparse matrices.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, NumPy arrays only have one dtype. You can see in the NumPy documentation:

```
A numpy array is homogeneous, and contains elements described by a dtype object. A dtype object can be constructed from different combinations of fundamental numeric types.
```

Further reading: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html